# SQL Server: Replace all instances of a string across all columns in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue where a BCP call to one of our stored procedures returns the NUL (\0) value character whenever it finds a column with an empty string as its content. This NUL cannot be processed by the caller, and I need to find a solution on either SQL script level or data insertion level to fix this.

My idea is to replace all empty strings with a proper NULL, as that is returned by BCP as an empty string. For a small table this could be done by CASE statements or similar, but my table has around 50 varchar columns with tens of thousands of rows being pulled at once, so I'm worried this would result in big performace issues.

Is there a way to manipulate an output of a select statement in a way where all occurances of a certain character/string, across all columns and rows, are replaced with another character/string?

Comment: No. You could generate the `SELECT` statement using dynamic SQL, but there's nothing within T-SQL itself. It does sound like the problem ought to be fixed through either the `bcp` invocation or through the caller or by changing the approach itself entirely; an empty string and `NULL` are different things and there's no reason why an empty string should be impossible to process.

Comment: If you would not store empty varchar colums as empty strings but as NULL as it supposed to be, you would not have this problem. So you should do 2 things: 1 do a one time conversion of your data and replace all empty strings by NULL and 2 edit your data layer so that no empty strings are stored anymore but NULL is stored instead

Comment: Without seeing your existing `bcp` command and your sample file it's hard to say for sure

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be either to update the data, update your process to properly handle empty strings, or use something like `NULLIF(col, '')` on the selected columns.